# Is there a way to find the size of the variable in R while the code is running?

Tags: r, ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I'm running the code in RStudio. I have a variable size of which defines how long the code is going to be running. I don't want to stop the code, because it has been running for some time now and this is all time sensitive. I want to make sure that I have enough time to finish the run, so I need to know size of this variable without stopping the code. I'm curious if there is a way to do that.

P.S. I'm running it on Ubuntu 16.04 machine

Comment: R is (for the most part) single-threaded, so I think "no". Once R is "working", you don't have access to objects to detect size or anything else.

Comment: You cannot determine the variable size when you are running the script like @r2evans mentioned. For next time you can make it part of the script by using this fucntion `object.size()`